# Within a shell script, how can I schedule a function to run at a specified time?

Tags: bash, shell-script, at

In a bash script, I have some code that needs to run when the script is executed, then a function that I want executed at a specific time. How can I do that?

```bsh
# Do this now
read -s -p "Password: " password

backup() {
  7z ... -p$password
}

# Do this starting at 5am - how?
while true; do
  backup
  sleep 86400
done
```

I've looked at `at`, but the man page is very scant, without any examples. I can't tell if or how to schedule a *function*. Do I need the extract that function to an external file?

In case this is an XY problem, what I want to do is a password-protected backup every morning at 5am. The first part of the script asks for the password via `read`, and feeds it via an environment variable to `7z`. The archiving part can be put in a `while true;` loop that sleeps for 86400 seconds to implement the "daily" part. The problem is starting at 5am. `cron` doesn't seem like a good option because the password should be persisted in a file, which is less secure than typing it once.

Comment: In the `at` script, you can define a function and then call it.  But if you want to do it every day, it's more suited for `cron`.

Comment: @DopeGhoti: `cron` was my first thought, but how do I pass the password to `7z` securely?

Answer (score 1):

If my math is right:

```
sleep $(( 86400 + 5*3600 - $(date +%s) % 86400 ))
echo "it's 5 in the morning (UTC)"
```

`$(date +%s)` = current time in seconds since start of 1970 (in UTC);
`$(date +%s) % 86400` = the current day's portion of that, i.e. seconds since last midnight (UTC)
`86400 + 5*3600` = seconds from last midnight to 5 AM tomorrow
`86400 + 5*3600 - $(date +%s) % 86400` = seconds from now to 5 AM tomorrow (UTC)

Of course that breaks if the current time is between the UTC midnight and the target time; and you need to adjust for the target time for the local timezone...

Perhaps a bit more straightforward would be:

```
sleep $(( $(date -d '05:00 tomorrow' +%s) - $(date +%s) ))
```

Which also skips an extra 24 hours if it's past midnight, but at least it counts local time.

> because the password should be persisted in a file, which is less secure than typing it once.

Depending on what you want to guard against, you might drop the password in some
in-memory filesystem i.e. `tmpfs`, so it wouldn't hit the disk. On a systemd system, `/run` should be `tmpfs`, but better make sure.

Also depending on how you do the backup, you might arrange for e.g. an SSH key that can only be used to send the backups to a remote (but not read them). Or use public-key encryption so you'd only need to have the public part of the backup on the host writing the backups...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make `at` run a shell function but you can have e.g. `at` send a signal, wait for that signal in a running script and start the function when the signal arrives.

If this script runs as `root` then you do not need the `--user` for `systemd-run`.

```
#! /bin/bash

backup() {
  : 7z ... -p$password
}

trap sighandler_usr1 USR1

sighandler_usr1 () {
  trap '' USR1 # do not execute backup() several times in parallel
  echo "PID $$ just received SIGUSR1"
  backup
  trap sighandler_usr1 USR1
  request_signal
}

request_signal () {
  : use e.g. at or systemd-run to send SIGUSR1 to this shell
  systemd-run --user --on-calendar=05:00 kill -USR1 $$
}

request_signal

while true; do
  read -s -n 1000 ignore
done
```